# mac & nginx config

Tags: nginx, mac, config

Здравствуйте,
помогите настроить конфиг nginx на маке

```
    server {
  listen 192.168.0.122:80;
  server_name 192.168.0.122;

  root /Users/dev/Documents/Projects/app1/public;
  try_files $uri /sites/192.168.0.122$uri @usersite;

  location @usersite {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host 192.168.0.122;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.122:8081;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

В /Users/dev/Documents/Projects/app1/public/sites/192.168.0.122 лежат некоторые файлы, все остальное должно подгружаться с 192.168.0.122:8081

Проблема в том, что не подгружаются файлы из папки 192.168.0.122. Хотя, такой же конфиг работает на убунте.

В чем может быть проблема и как ее решить?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

сделайте так

```
root /Users/dev/Documents/Projects/app1/public;
location / {
      try_files $uri /sites/192.168.0.122$uri @usersite;
}
```